# change TextInputLayout hint position to right

Tags: android, android-design-library, android-textinputlayout

Is there anyway to put the TextInputLayout hint at right on top of the editText? and also I don't want editText position to be changed.setting the TextInputLayout gravity to right didn't work,Although it changes the editText position.

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya TextInputLayout gravity you mean?

Answer (score 0):

`TextInputLayout` is designed to meet the [floating inline labels material design guidelines](https://www.google.com/design/spec/components/text-fields.html#text-fields-labels), which specify that the hint floats along the start of the `EditText`.