# Change TextInputLayout floating hint position to middle?

Tags: android, xml

How can I change TextInputLayout floating hint position to middle?

I've [read](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36434902) this answer and others about the same subject but they're over a year old.

I'm asking this question to see if there are any changes in 2017.

Comment: I haven't tried it, but you could look into modifying [`TextInputLayout`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support.git/+/master/design/src/android/support/design/widget/TextInputLayout.java) and changing [the gravity that is set](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support.git/+/master/design/src/android/support/design/widget/TextInputLayout.java#202) on the [`CollapsingTextHelper`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support.git/+/master/design/src/android/support/design/widget/CollapsingTextHelper.java).

Comment: Would it be acceptable for the non-floating hint to be in the middle (in addition to the floating hint being in the middle) if the user-entered text was still on the left?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The behavior that you want exists inside the `CollapsingTextHelper` class. Unfortunately, this class is package-private and `final`, so there's no officially supported way for you to call the methods you'd like. Here's what you'd love to be able to write:

```
private void setCollapsedHintMiddle(TextInputLayout layout) {
    CollapsingTextHelper helper = layout.getCollapsingTextHelper();
    helper.setCollapsedTextGravity(Gravity.TOP | Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
}
```

Since you can't do it that way, you can hack around it using reflection:

```
private void setCollapsedHintMiddle(TextInputLayout layout) {
    try {
        Field helperField = TextInputLayout.class.getDeclaredField("mCollapsingTextHelper");
        helperField.setAccessible(true);
        Object helper = helperField.get(layout);

        Method setterMethod = helper.getClass().getDeclaredMethod("setCollapsedTextGravity", int.class);
        setterMethod.setAccessible(true);
        setterMethod.invoke(helper, Gravity.TOP | Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
    }
    catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
        // TODO
    }
    catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
        // TODO
    }
    catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
        // TODO
    }
    catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
        // TODO
    }
}
```

Note that this relies on the internal implementation details of both `TextInputLayout` and `CollapsingTextHelper`, and could break at any time.

### Edit

As I alluded to in my comment on the original question, there's an officially-supported way to do something that is not quite what you want. If you declare your `TextInputLayout` like this:

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
    android:id="@+id/email"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
        android:id="@+id/emailChild"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:hint="Email"/>

</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

And then in Java update the `TextInputEditText`'s gravity:

```
    EditText emailChild = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.emailChild);
    emailChild.setGravity(Gravity.START);
```

The resulting behavior will be that the **hint** is displayed horizontally centered (both when the view has focus/text and when it does not) while the **user-entered text** is displayed on the left.